# Swap DIV’s horizontally when ‘float’ won’t work properly (using CSS)

Tags: css

```
<td width="100%">
  <h1 class="*"></h1>
  <div class="DIV ONE"></div>
  <div class="DIV TWO"></div>
```

The problem is a bit more complex than the title implies.. What i want to achieve is put ‘DIV TWO’ on the same line with ‘DIV ONE’ (which can be done with *{display: inline;}* or *{display: table-footer/header-group;}* ), **but swap their orders** (put ‘DIV TWO’ before ‘DIV ONE’).
Which is where i’m stuck, since {float: right;} on ‘DIV ONE’ puts it all the way to the right of the page and {margin-right} does nothing.

I want them close to each other and aligned to the left, like so:

```css
 ___________________________________________________________________________
|td                                                                         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    h1                                                                     |
|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------   |
|  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _                                          |
| |                |               |                                        |
| |  DIV TWO       |   DIV ONE     |                                        |
| |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |                                        |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
```

What is the best way tho accomplish this with CSS ?

Comment: do you have any browser constraints?

Comment: why not change their html order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add position: relative to their parent class and then

```
.ONE {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px; //change this to width of div two 
}

.TWO {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: good luck with this if you have content below these divs or if your h1 grows to a size greater than 100px

Answer (score 1):

As your divs are inline-block elements you should be able to use the `direction` css property:

```css
table {width:100%;}
td {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
.DIV {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="DIV ONE">one</div>
      <div class="DIV TWO">two</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[More info about direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

otherwise you could use the float everything method

```css
.container,
.TWO {float:left;}
.ONE {float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="DIV ONE">one</div>
    <div class="DIV TWO">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m probably doing it wrong, because it didn’t work. Perhaps because i posted the HTML code wrong (i fixed it now). Where tbody > tr > td is the container of the two elements i want swapped.
But i tried it anyway and it didn’t work. If the corrected html code makes a change, please advise.
I should point out that there are lots of other things in tbody > tr > td besides the mentioned div’s.

Comment: any reason you are using a td with width 100%; that looks alike you are using a table for layout which is a big no-no.  I have edited the above to use a table instead.  If you have loads of other stuff in the td though you may want to add the wrapper div around the two divs you want the order changing for

Comment: This works now!, after your edit. Though using this method means i have to set separate ‘heights’ and ‘margins' for the two div’s (in order to have them aligned perfectly), because one is slightly thinner than the other and changing the margin (or height) for it, affects the other one as well.

Still, it worked. Thank You.

Comment: add `vertical-align:top` to `.DIV` as they are inline elements they will be aligned like different sized words in a sentence

Answer (score 1):

I like how `twitter-bootstrap` does it, so the answer is based on it :)

```css
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    left: 25%;    
    width: 75%;    
}

.right {
    right: 75%;    
    width: 25%;    
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Left element</div>
<div class="right">Right element</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf4srcxr/)

Comment: This seems to hide one of the DIV’s (according to which one i set first).
Furthermore, it pushes the third div up (the one underneath the two i mentioned, which i don’t want to modify), overlapping the div’s i’m interested in.

Comment: I can't see anything saying about the third div in your question :)